# How do I read this piece of this python using lambda example?

Tags: python, lambda

Do you know how to read this piece of this python example?

```
dual = Graph([f_edges,lambda f1,f2: set(f1).intersection([(e[1],e[0]) for e in f2])])
```

I'd like to see exactly what contains the parameter of the Sage project.

The code has been taken from here:
- https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/6236

### And the Sage documentation of the Graph function is here:

http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html#graph-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambdas are ways of writing anonymous functions, functions that are only going to be used once where it might be more succinct than creating a regular named function with `def`. This one could be implemented as a regular function like this:

```
def intersect(f1, f2):
    elems = [(e[1], e[0]) for e in f2]
    return set(f1).intersection(elems)
```

and the outer code would look like:

```
dual = Graph([f_edges, intersect])
```

That is, it looks like Graph is expecting as an argument a list where the first element is whatever `f_edges` is and the second argument is a function taking two parameters. Perhaps your confusion with this is that from this line alone, neither the `intersect` function nor the lambda get called directly. Presumably, though, `Graph` will internally make a call to the function it was supplied with.